# Cannot read property 'length' of null (typeahead)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm having a little trouble with Twitter Typeahead. It throws me the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null            jquery.js:4`

I've looked at some other cases, but none of them match mine.

**My Code:**

```
    var companies = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '_companies?query=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });

    var users = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('username'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '_users?query=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });

    companies.initialize();
    users.initialize();

    $('#username').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, {
        name: 'companies',
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: companies.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            header: '<h4 class="hint-title">Bedrijven</h4>'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'users',
        displayKey: 'username',
        source: users.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            header: '<h4 class="hint-title">Gebruikers</h4>'
        }
    });
```

Maybe there is someone else who has/had a similar issue?

Comment: If you use chrome's (or any debugger's) "pause on exceptions," you can see the exact line of code that throws the error.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat Found it. It is a very long line of code in `jquery.js`

Comment: @Whothehellisthat Never mind, it's actually short. It's on line 4 in `jquery.js`. `e.length, a = M(e);`

Comment: Does that help you figure it out? If not, you could use the unminified jQuery version to show you the real code, with the full variable names and such to help you debug.

Sorry I can't give more specific help; I'm not familiar with the Twitter API and such. Just trying to help you figure it out... ^^

Comment: @Whothehellisthat I'm not familiar with it either haha. I have no clue what is causing it to crash on that line.

Comment: Have you tried using the non-minified version of jQuery? It could help you figure out what the jQuery code is doing. Look for "uncompressed, development" on the download page.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat Yeah I pretty printed the code from `jquery.js`. Still doesn't help me to figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117884/discussion-between-whothehellisthat-and-chris).

Comment: Issue still exists. No fix yet.

Comment: Did you see my comment in that chat?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat I commented about 6 hours ago..

Comment: Oh. Sorry--didn't see a notification. Will reply in an hour or two, sorry